# How to create json package manager

Tags: python, node.js, json, npm, requirements.txt

Need to create `json package manager`/ `software package manager`, So I have `requirnmnet.txt` file for NodeJS.

All the dependencies for NodeJS should be in that requirnmnet.txt file

kindly help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS already got a file that is similar to Python's `requirements.txt`.

Inside of your `package.json` file, create a new key called `dependencies`.

It will contain all dependencies your program needs:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "Package_Name": "Version"
}
```

Then, type `npm install` inside of your project folder to install all the dependencies.

You can search all downloadable modules and versions here:

- https://npmjs.com

Comment: Need to create `package.json` manually or is there any way to create it automatically

Comment: @Digital_AI you can create it by typing `npm init -y` inside of the folder

Comment: getting error` 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` 
so for that need to install nodejs on system?

Comment: @Digital_AI you have to download and install NodeJS from https://nodejs.org/en/download